# Abelian-by-(finite abelian)

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

hope you all doing fine.
I have a question. Is it true that a abelian-by-(finite abelian) group is also (finite abelian)-by-abelian?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: You need to say what you mean by an A-by-B group, since there are two opposite conventions for this.

Comment: I meant that can we find a finite abelian normal subgroup N such that the quotient G/N is abelian?

Comment: Oh I am sorry, I am new :)

Comment: A-by-B means G has a normal subgroup N such that N has the property A, and the quotient G/N has the property B.

Answer (score 3):

In fact it is not true in either direction.

The infinite dihedral group is abelian-by-finite abelian, but not (finite abelian)-by-abelian.

A central product of infinite many copies of $D_8$ is (finite abelian)-by-abelian, but not abelian-by-(finite abelian).